# Adding LSTM layers before the softmax layer

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, reinforcement-learning

I would like to add an LSTM layer before the softmax layer so that I can keep track of the context of a sequence and use it for prediction. Following is my implementation but I get every time the following error. Please help me to solve this error.

**ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2**

```
    common_model = Sequential()
    common_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=self.state_size, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    common_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    common_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    common_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    common_model.add(Flatten())
    common_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    common_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    common_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    common_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    common_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    common_model.add(Dropout(0.5))


    agent_model = Sequential()
    agent_model.add(common_model)
    agent_model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False))
    agent_model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='softmax'))
    agent_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.agent_learning_rate))

    critic_model = Sequential()
    critic_model.add(common_model)
    critic_model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    critic_model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(lr=self.critic_learning_rate))
```

Comment: At which line exactly does the error pop up?

Comment: because you added a flatten layer you can't use LSTM after that.

Comment: @desertnaut the error pops up at ***agent_model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False))***

Comment: or you need to use `TimeDistributed` layer in each layer before flatten

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ I commented flatten_layer and encountered similar error  **ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4**

Comment: Might be of help: [How to connect a dense to a LSTM](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/915)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add dense layer before LSTM layer in keras or Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714688/add-dense-layer-before-lstm-layer-in-keras-or-tensorflow)

Comment: Does it make sense to do what you're trying? Is any of the spatial dimensions of your images something that should be seen as a time series?

Comment: @DanielMöller I am not sure if I understand your question but yes I am trying to make a sequence of transformations of an image.

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4172

Answer (score 1):

I still don't quite understand the purpose of appending LSTM after Dense, but that error can be explained:

Because in Keras, the LSTM accept the input tensor like `(?, m, n)` which need to have 3 dims, while the output of Dense is (?, p) which has 2 dims.

You may want to try Embedding or Reshape layer, for example:

`model.add(Embedding(512, 64, input_length=512))`

or

`model.add(Reshape((512, 64)))`

Also it is good to check some examples of using LSTM: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/examples